# HTTP request matching different endpoint - gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I have the following to handler functions, DataSetsGet and RetrieveSharedData.
When make request with the URL
https://127.0.0.1:20000/nfdm-fdm/v2/shared-data, I get response from DataSetsGet handler instead of RetrieveSharedData handler function. When I take the bracket from {id} to id, I get the right response from RetrieveSharedData handler. Any help to solve this issue, my code below with omitted codes.

```
func DataSetsGet(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

// Data set response codes
}

func RetrieveSharedData(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
// Retrieve shared data response codes
}



type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

var Router = NewRouter()

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        var handler http.Handler
        handler = route.HandlerFunc

        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(handler)
    }

    return router
}


var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "DataSetsGet",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/nfdm-fdm/v2/{id}",
        DataSetsGet,
    },

    Route{
        "RetrieveSharedData",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/nfdm-fdm/v2/shared-data",
        RetrieveSharedData,
    },

}


func main{

addr := "127.0.0.1:6060"

server := NewServer(addr)

go func() {
        err := server.ListenAndServe() 
        if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            logger.Log.Errorf("Could not listen on %s: %v\n", addr, err)
        }
    }()
}



// Create a new server
func NewServer(ListAddr string) *http.Server {

    return &http.Server{
        Addr:         ListAddr,
        Handler:      Router,
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
}
```

Comment: `/nfdm-fdm/v2/shared-data` clearly matches the pattern `/nfdm-fdm/v2/{id}`; the router can't know that "shared-data" isn't an ID. Try swapping the order of the routes.

Comment: As documented here https://github.com/gorilla/mux#matching-routes  `If two routes match, the first one wins:`. You can further specifies the format of each URL parameter using a regular expression. Using `{id:[0-9]+}` would help the framework distinguish a call to SetGet / Retrieve, assuming this ID is of number kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reorder your routes and make sure to include the static routes before the regex routes which would cause the static routes to take the precedence if perfectly matched before the regex routes.

```golang
var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "RetrieveSharedData",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/nfdm-fdm/v2/shared-data",
        RetrieveSharedData,
    },
    Route{
        "DataSetsGet",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/nfdm-fdm/v2/{id}",
        DataSetsGet,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fix the `dataSetsGet` function and the `route handler function` as follows

```golang
func DataSetsGet(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, id string) {
        response.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("myID %s", id)))
}


var routes = Routes{
        Route{
                "DataSetsGet",
                strings.ToUpper("Get"),
                "/nfdm-fdm/v2/dataset/{id}",
                func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                        vars := mux.Vars(r)
                        ID := strings.ToLower(vars["id"])
                        DataSetsGet(w, r, ID)
                },
        },

        Route{
                "RetrieveSharedData",
                strings.ToUpper("Get"),
                "/nfdm-fdm/v2/shared-data",
                RetrieveSharedData,
        },
}
```

###### curl

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:6060/nfdm-fdm/v2/dataset/1234'

curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:6060/nfdm-fdm/v2/shared-data'
```

I have changed the API path. As suggested by mkopriva, mixing dynamic and static segment is not possible with gorilla mux.

The complete code snippet can be found on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f_MtJUAjj5U) here.

Comment: Am these paths based on a specification and therefore cannot be changed. Anyway thanks for pointing this issue.